# Error: Downloading broken file by fread in php

Tags: php, http-headers, fread, download

I tried different codes to download files from php.

**fileread() give issues** so, that is not even an option now.

I am trying to use fread() now, But the problem it gives is that when you download a file, that file never works. I download broken file. For example if I download image file it will give the error Invalid Image in picasa. (Shown Below)

[image: Broken file after downloading]

Following is the code I am using:

```
<?php
    require '../php/db.php'; // Database Connection (No issue in this)
    ob_start();
    set_time_limit(0);  // To set script time to infinity.
    ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
    if(isset($_GET['file_id'])&&!empty($_GET['file_id'])) download_file($_GET['file_id']);  // calling a function download_file given below
    else die("There was an error in downloading file. Please try again later.");

function download_file($id){
    global $con;  // For database connection
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,htmlentities($id));
    $file="SELECT file_name,file_title,file_size,down FROM files WHERE file_id= $id"; // Taking file info from database
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$file);
    if($result) echo "Okay!";
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $name = $row['file_name'];  // File is stored with this name in same dir
    $title = $row['file_title'];
    $ext = ext($name);
    $down = $row['down']; // Tells number of downloads
    $newname = $title.'.'.$ext; // Changing file name while downloading.
    $down++;

    if(is_file($name)) {
        $update_down = "UPDATE files SET down = $down WHERE file_id = '$id'";
        $update_down_result = mysqli_query($con,$update_down); // Increment number of downloads

        download_by_fread($name,$newname); // Calling a function

        exit;

    }else header("Location: ../index.php?msg=Sorry!+File+could+not+found!");
}

function download_by_fread($name,$newname){
    if($fd=fopen($name, "rb")){

        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false);
        header("Content-type: ".tell_file_type($name));
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$newname."\"");
        header("Content-length: ".filesize($name));
        header("Cache-control: public"); //use this to open files directly

        while(!feof($fd)) {
            print(fread($fd, 4096));
            ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    }else header("Location: ../index.php?msg=Sorry!+File+could+not+found!");
    fclose($fd);
}

function ext($name){
    $rut = strrev($name);
    $erut = explode('.', $rut);
    return strrev($erut[0]);
}

function tell_file_type($file_name){
    $rut = strrev($file_name);
    $erut = explode('.', $rut);
    $ext = strrev($erut[0]);    
    switch($ext){
        case 'txt': return 'text/plain'; break;
        case 'rar':
        case 'zip': return 'application/x-compressed'; break;
        case 'gif': return 'image/gif'; break;
        case 'jpg':
        case 'jpeg': return 'image/jpeg'; break;
        case 'bmp': return 'image/bmp'; break;
        case 'png': return 'image/png'; break;
        case 'pdf': return 'application/pdf'; break;
        case 'mp3': return 'audio/mpeg3'; break;
        case 'mp4': return 'video/mp4'; break;
        case 'mkv': return 'video/mkv'; break;
        case 'mpg': return 'video/mpeg'; break;
        case 'avi': return 'video/avi'; break;
        case 'wav': return 'audio/wav'; break;
        case 'doc':
        case 'docx': return 'application/msword'; break;
        case 'pps':
        case 'ppt':
        case 'pptx': return 'application/mspowerpoint'; break;
        case 'xls':
        case 'xlsx': return 'application/excel'; break;
        case 'exe': return 'application/octet-stream'; break;
        case 'swf': return 'application/x-shockwave-flash'; break;
    }
}

?>
```

Help me finding error in this code please.

Thank you.

**ANSWER:** 
I found the error. I was echoing "Okay!" after mysql_query. to check if query is successful. We can do that or it will be added to file. and file will become invalid.

Comment: there must be some blank lines in your code. There may be some spaces in ../php/db.php in this file also.

Comment: blank lines? I don't get it. and db.php is for database connection. it is connected without any issue. Counter is also updated properly. The main problem is in downloading the file.

Comment: some blank spaces/ lines will be there in page . you can check this by just change the exxtension of your image file to .txt and open it in some editor , you will find some blank lines on top of your code , if you will remove those lines and save and again change the extesion the image will work

Comment: That removes the problem of invalid file but still gives the same issue which was generated by fileread(). Some big files is not completely downloaded. May be that's the problem of script execution time.
If you want to see the problem please follow this [link](http://www.skyshare.in).

If you will download a small file it will work fine. but the problem starts with big files. ~10 MB.

Comment: please check the @ Frank Bardon Jr. answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `?>` from the ends of your PHP files, and make certain there are no spaces before the `<?php` at the beginning.

What may be happening is that PHP is sending " " blank space characters to the output of the image. This would cause a corrupt file if there is anything outside of the PHP brackets as these would automatically be sent to the browser as content.

Comment: I found the problem. I was echo "Okay!" after mysql_query. to check if query is successful.